# SwingWorker gives "Cannot find symbol" error when referring to class members

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Link to a paste of the compilation errors together with the SSCE:
http://pastebin.com/upYzbHN1

Filename is 'foo.java'. Compiled with 'javac foo.java'.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class foo extends JFrame {
        HashMap<Integer,Thing> Things = new HashMap<Integer,Thing>();
        JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();

        public void findThings() {
                SwingWorker<HashMap<Integer,Thing>,Thing> sw1 = new SwingWorker<HashMap<Integer,Thing>,Thing>() {
                        protected HashMap<Integer,Thing> doInBackground() {
                                HashMap<Integer,Thing> things = new HashMap<Integer,Thing>();
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                return things;
                        }

                        protected void process(List<Thing> chunks) {
                                for(Thing thing : chunks) {
                                        this.things.put(thing.id, thing);
                                        this.jtp.setText(String.valueOf(this.things.size()));
                                }
                        }
                };

                sw1.execute();
        }

        public foo() {
                super();
                setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JButton jbtn = new JButton("findThings()");
                jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                findThings();
                        }
                });
                add(jbtn);
                this.jtp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
                add(this.jtp); 

                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                pack();
                setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void foo(String[] args) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                new foo();
                        }
                });
        }

        private class Thing {
                public Thing() {
                        id = 100;
                        name = "Thing's name";
                }

                Integer id = null;
                String name = null;
        }
}
```

Gives these compilation errors:

```
foo.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
                                        this.things.put(thing.id, thing);
                                            ^
  symbol: variable things
foo.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                                        this.jtp.setText(String.valueOf(this.thi
ngs.size()));
                                                                            ^
  symbol: variable things
foo.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                                        this.jtp.setText(String.valueOf(this.thi
ngs.size()));
                                            ^
  symbol: variable jtp
3 errors
```

Comment: @Mat: this is not the only reason though. `this` is the SwingWorker, not the foo instance.

Comment: What good is `process(...)` without `publish(...)`?

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance `Map` is called `Things` (capital letter - wrong convention for variable naming by the way).

You are referencing it by calling `things` (lowercase letter - variables should be named camelBack, so that's the right name to use).

**Edit**

Also as mentioned in other answers, `this` will refer to the worker thread, not to the `Foo` class instance.

- Use `Foo.this.things`.
- Change your declaration to:

  `HashMap<Integer,Thing> things = new HashMap<Integer,Thing>(); //
         lowercased variable name`
- Change your class name to `Foo`
- Check the Java coding conventions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Answer (score 2):

You defined an anonymous inner class extending SwingWorker. Inside the methods of this class, `this` refers to the current instance of the anonymous SwingWorker class. It does not refer to the current `foo` instance.

Drop `this.`, or use `foo.this.jtp` (and fix your case issues, and respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter, whereas methods and variables start with a lowercase letter).

```
protected void process(List<Thing> chunks) {
    for(Thing thing : chunks) {
        things.put(thing.id, thing); // first way
        Foo.this.jtp.setText(String.valueOf(this.things.size())); // second way
    }
}
```

(code snippet assuming respect of the conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive. Therefore the variable `things` is not defined in the class `foo` rather its called `Things`. Also the variable is not defined within the scope of the anonymous `SwingWorker` class. You can use

```
Foo.this.things.put(thing.id, thing);
Foo.this.jtp.setText(String.valueOf(Foo.this.things.size()));
```

This follows [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) where classes start with an *uppercase* letter and variables start with a *lowercase* letter.

which involves renaming

- class `foo` -> `Foo`
- variable `Things` -> `things`